# Custom Configuration Section (Array) in appsettings.json

Tags: .net-core, configuration, appsettings

I have an array of objects in my appsettings.json file:

```
"CustomFields": [
    {
      "GUID": "be283d29-12f0-4e02-be9f-050d7901269a",
      "Key": "Key1",
      "Type": 1
    },
    {
      "GuidValue": "d8a2a939-fa5d-4b81-bdae-a53dce7d90b3",
      "Key": "Key2",
      "Type": 1
    },
    {
      "GuidValue": "83302d3e-2a5f-4ea4-a250-80b939ef8b65",
      "Key": "Key3",
      "Type": 1
    }
]
```

I would like to create an appsettings.Production.json that replaces guid values that are different, but keeps settings that have the same guids. So my appsettings.Production.json would look like:

```
"CustomFields": [
    {
      "GUID": "d9fa38aa-e676-49df-b75e-d643cdbfb18c",
      "Key": "Key1",
      "Type": 1
    }
]
```

but all 3 settings would still be available to the application. Currently it's replacing the entire configuration section and only the field overridden in the appsettings.Production.json is available.

I've looked at custom builders, custom configuration providers but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to do this.

Could someone please tell me how to replace only certain values from the config sections?

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue when preparing app settings of my project. Here is the workaround:

Prepare 3 app settings json files:
- `appsettings.json`
- `appsettings.Development.json`
- `appsettings.Production.json`

1. `CustomFields` in `appsettings.json`:

```
"CustomFields": []
```

2. `CustomFields` in `appsettings.Development.json`:
   *(Here I assume that these 3 items are development-only data.)*

```
"CustomFields": [
    {
      "GUID": "be283d29-12f0-4e02-be9f-050d7901269a",
      "Key": "Key1",
      "Type": 1
    },
    {
      "GuidValue": "d8a2a939-fa5d-4b81-bdae-a53dce7d90b3",
      "Key": "Key2",
      "Type": 1
    },
    {
      "GuidValue": "83302d3e-2a5f-4ea4-a250-80b939ef8b65",
      "Key": "Key3",
      "Type": 1
    }
]
```

3. `CustomFields` in `appsettings.Production.json`:

```
"CustomFields": [
    {
      "GUID": "d9fa38aa-e676-49df-b75e-d643cdbfb18c",
      "Key": "Key1",
      "Type": 1
    }
]
```